# How to form list of all OwnValues of symbols in Global context?

Tags: evaluation, variable-definitions, variable

How do I get the list of all `OwnValues` of symbols in the `` Global` `` context?

All my attempts have failed because `OwnValues` insists taking only `Symbol`, and `Names[]` only returns a list of `String`:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = 3;
OwnValues[Evaluate[Symbol[#]]] & /@ Names["Global`*"]
```

> OwnValues::sym : Argument 3 at position 1 expected to be a symbol
>
> ```
> {OwnValues[3]}
> ```

Converting the `String` to `Symbol` causes the `Symbol` to evaluate before it enters `OwnValues`.

Comment: Somebody will find the duplicate, but in the mean time, you can use: ``Cases[Names["Global`*"], x_ /; ToExpression[x, InputForm, OwnValues]=!={}]``

Comment: Also, ``Language`ExtendedDefinition`` is a useful function that accepts strings and returns a list of *Values plus a few other pieces of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same code structure, for example, you can use the fact that [`MakeExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeExpression.html) returns [`HoldComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldComplete.html):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = 3;
ReleaseHold@Hold[OwnValues][MakeExpression[#]] & /@ Names["Global`*"]
```

> `{{HoldPattern[a] :> 3}}`

**edit**

Then using b3m2a1's suggestion,

```
Join@@ToExpression[Names["Global`*"], StandardForm, OwnValues]
```

returns the desired list.

Comment: Use the third argument to [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) to make this more concise. i.e. ``ToExpression[Names["Global`*"], StandardForm, OwnValues]``

Comment: @b3m2a1 ...and using `Join` to put it all together: ``Join@@ToExpression[Names["Global`*"], StandardForm, OwnValues]``